# Excel Slicer Manipulation with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am learning how create and manipulate Excel slicers with VBA.  I have been following some examples by Paul Te Braack on his "Business Intelligence Website:  https://paultebraak.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/accessing-the-slicer-through-vba/

When I try to cycle through the items of a slicer cache and print the values of "caption", "value" and "name" in the immediate window, it returns an error of "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error for the line: " This is the code: "Set SL = sC.SlicerCacheLevels(1)"

```
Sub BTest()
Dim sC As SlicerCache
Dim SL As SlicerCacheLevel
Dim sI As SlicerItem

application.EnableEvents = False
application.Calculation = xlManual
Set sC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(5)
Set SL = sC.SlicerCacheLevels(1)
Debug.Print “——————————————————————————”

For Each sI In SL.SlicerItems
Debug.Print “Caption; – > ” & sI.Caption
Debug.Print “Value; – > ” + CStr(sI.Value)
Debug.Print “Unique; Name; – > ” + sI.Name
Debug.Print “——————————————————————————”

Next
application.EnableEvents = True
application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

I modified the code, but my modified code returns the results "False," "False," and "Sheet5False" are returned.  The pivot table and the slicer are in Sheet5 by the way.  (which I think should work based on the slicer cache and item verifications mentioned below.)

When I review the slicer cached in the locals window, it shows it has 30 items, and I can expand the items and display the values of the caption, value, and name.

When I type "Debug.Print sC.SlicerItems.Count" in the immediate window it returns an answer of 30. When I type "Debug.Print sC.SlicerItems(2).Name in the immediate window it returns the answer of 30.

The modified code is:

```
Sub CTest()
Dim sC As SlicerCache
Dim SL As SlicerCacheLevel
Dim sI As SlicerItem

application.EnableEvents = False
application.Calculation = xlManual
Set sC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(5)
Set sI = sC.SlicerItems(1)
Debug.Print “——————————————————————————”

For Each sI In sC.SlicerItems
Debug.Print “Caption; – > ” & sI.Caption
Debug.Print “Value; – > ” + CStr(sI.Value)
Debug.Print “Unique; Name; – > ” + sI.Name
Debug.Print “——————————————————————————”

Next
application.EnableEvents = True
application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Any guidance on what I am doing wrong in the original code example or the modified code example will be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SlicerItemLevels is only applicable to OLAP data feeds. See this [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193891(v=office.15).aspx).

It seems that the website you copied the code from used ASCII characters 147 (“) & 148 (”) for open and close quotes. VBA expects ASCII character 34 (") for both. The following should work just fine.

```
Sub CTest()
Dim sC As SlicerCache
Dim SL As SlicerCacheLevel
Dim sI As SlicerItem

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Set sC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(5)
Set sI = sC.SlicerItems(1)
Debug.Print "——————————————————————————"

For Each sI In sC.SlicerItems
Debug.Print "Caption; – > " & sI.Caption
Debug.Print "Value; – > " + CStr(sI.Value)
Debug.Print "Unique; Name; – > " + sI.Name
Debug.Print "——————————————————————————"

Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks  for your help.  I fixed my revised code, using the ASCII character 34 in place of Char 147 and 148 and it works great.  This is a good lesson for me.  Also thank you for pointing out the scope of SlicerItemLevels.